# Show UIViewController in Framework by calling a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, ios-frameworks

I am making a framework for third part developer which will create a View like interstitial ads.
This is how I create myViewController(inside Framework) object from Applications RootViewController class.

```
myViewController *ViewController =[[myViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Currently I am able to load my view in test app by doing

```
[self.view addSubview:ViewController.view];
```

instead I want third party developer to call my method (showScreen) like

```
    [ViewController showScreen];
```

and this should create the View by going into viewDidLoad or init of myViewController Class.

This is my rootviewcontroller function look like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     myViewController *ViewController =[[myViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:nil];
     [self.view addSubview:ViewController.view]; //Dont Want to use this
//   [ViewController showScreen];          //Want to use something like this
```

}

This opens up my xib file attached to the myViewController

```
 @implementation myViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no difference if you use `framework`, `static library` whatever...

You can present `UIViewController` directly from root viewController

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

f.e

```
[self presentViewController:yourViewController animated:animated completion:completionHandler];
```

Or you can pass root viewController to your own `UIViewController` to present from it

```
[yourViewController showFromViewController:self];
```